# Why can't a string from a tuple not be inserted as the fieldname in the table update command in SQLlite3 in python?

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

when i try to use a stringvalue from a tuple as the columnname in my executemany() command, like this:

```
tup = ('field', 'value',)

cursor.executemany('UPDATE table SET ?=?', tup)
```

i get a SQlite.operationalerror:

```
   c.executemany('''UPDATE table SET ?=?''', tup)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

when can't the tuple value not be inserted befor the '=' and only after??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a SQL parameter indicates a literal value, one that needs quoting to protect it from being interpreted as a SQL table or column name, or a literal.

In other words, your `field` value will be quoted:

```
UPDATE table SET "field"="value"
```

instead of

```
UPDATE table SET field="value"
```

You'll have to sanitize the value for `field` yourself to ensure that it *only* contains a field name and then interpolate it yourself:

```
'UPDATE table SET %s=?' % ('field',)
```

The sanitization is a hard problem; you perhaps should use a framework like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to generate the SQL for you in a sane manner instead.

Comment: so i would have to insert the fieldname by conventional python formtating, i.e. use 'blabla' + fieldname + 'blabla'?